# Authentication failed for gem installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, bundler

bundle install leads to error:

```
Fetching https://x-oauth-basic@github.com/MyCompanny/fiscal_calendar.git
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/MyCompanny/fiscal_calendar.git/'
Retrying `git clone 'https://x-oauth-basic@github.com/MyCompanny/fiscal_calendar.git'
```

it will eventually fails, although in the Gemfile:

```
pat = "OUR PERSONAL TOKEN HERE"
gem 'fiscal_calendar', '~> 0.1.2', git: "https://#{pat}:x-oauth-basic@github.com/MyCompanny/fiscal_calendar.git"
```

We are sure that our personal token is valid, however, we still get the error `Invalid username or password`.

Although in the log, it says:

```
git clone 'https://x-oauth-basic@github.com/MyCompanny/fiscal_calendar.git'
```

so, it seems not using the personal token?

Any idea?

Comment: Passwords/usernames/tokens should not be in the gemfile - instead use `bundle config` to set them out of band. See section `Credentials for Gem Sources` on https://bundler.io/v1.15/bundle_config.html

Comment: @fredrik I used this 
```export BUNDLE_GITHUB__COM=abcd0123generatedtoken:x-oauth-basic
``` but still facing same issue, keep asking for a password

Comment: With the actual token or that exact string you posted here?

Comment: with the real one of course :sweat: :)  , this issue raised in the past 2 days and trying to solve it 
simply bundler read the PAT but keep asking for a password

Answer (score 0):

After investigation, the Github personal token was found expired. It seems my testing against token expiry was not working, as the gems was actually cached.